# Defining a Tree in LISP (Racket)

Tags: racket, plai

I'm trying to define a tree using Racket's #plai language, though I'm struggling a bit when it comes to creating the tree through an "add-node" function.

The define-type I'm using goes like this:

```
(define-type BBT
  [empty]
  [leaf (elem number?)]
  [node (elem number?) (left BBT?) (right BBT?)])
```

And I'd like to construct a tree that looks like this:

```
(node 3 (empty) (node 5 (leaf 4) (leaf 6)))
```

Following this call:

```
(add-node 6 (add-node 4 (add-node 5 (add-node 3 (empty)))))
```

So far, I've tried the following:

```
(define (add-node n tree)
  (match tree
    [(empty) (node n (empty) (empty))]))
```

And that works for an empty tree, as it just adds a single node with empty trees at both sides, but I haven't found a way to construct a tree like the example I shared above.

Any tips or suggestions as to what should I do? I know I should use recursion when it catches the "node" case, but so far I haven't come up with a successful attempt.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how this works without introducing complicated things like an obscure racket language? Is this question about recursion or racket?

Comment: Your `add-node` is severely underspecified: does it add a new right branch, left branch, or what?  Is the node it adds a leaf?  Does it construct a new tree of which the existing tree is one of the branches?  If so which branch?  What is the other branch?

Answer (score 0):

From your example:

```
(add-node 6 (add-node 4 (add-node 5 (add-node 3 (empty)))))
```

is supposed to produce

```
(node 3 (empty) (node 5 (leaf 4) (leaf 6)))
```

This contains many calls to `add-node`, and that makes it more confusing. So to get a better idea of what you want, I'll start with the innermost call to `add-node`.

```
(add-node 3 (empty))
```

From the initial code in your question, it seems this should produce

```
(node 3 (empty) (empty))
```

So now replacing the innermost call in your larger example, it becomes

```
(add-node 6 (add-node 4 (add-node 5 (node 3 (empty) (empty)))))
=
(node 3 (empty) (node 5 (leaf 4) (leaf 6)))
```

Now I have to figure out what the next-innermost call is supposed to do.

```
(add-node 5 (node 3 (empty) (empty)))
```

In the final output the `3` stays on top and the `5` goes to the right node, so I can only guess that this call is supposed to produce

```
(node 3 (empty) (node 5 (empty) (empty)))
```

Now replacing that call in the larger example:

```
(add-node 6 (add-node 4 (node 3 (empty) (node 5 (empty) (empty)))))
=
(node 3 (empty) (node 5 (leaf 4) (leaf 6)))
```

The next innermost call is

```
(add-node 4 (node 3 (empty) (node 5 (empty) (empty))))
```

Now this is where I don't understand your logic. By the pattern of the previous example, the `4` should go into the rightmost node, "right-right". But in this example it seems to go in the left portion of the right node, "right-left". It doesn't seem to be going to the nearest empty node, which would be pure "left", so I don't know what pattern you're trying to make.

Please clarify your question and add more specifics if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out a way to construct the tree like this:

```
(define (add-node n tree)
  (match tree
    [(empty) (node n (empty) (empty))]
    [else (add-aux n tree)]))

(define (add-node-aux n tree)
  (match tree
    [(empty) (leaf n)]
    [(leaf e) (if (> e n)
                  (node e (leaf n) (empty))
                  (node e (empty) (leaf n)))]
    [(node e l r) (if (> e n)
                    (node e (add-node-aux n l) r)
                    (node e l (add-node-aux n r)))]))
```

It does the job but I was wondering if there's a way to create the tree without relying on the auxiliary function. Basically, I created the auxiliary call to prevent having trees with just one node (Root trees) being labeled as "leaves". So, instead of having the first element output a tree with shape (leaf 3), by calling the recursive function, it's possible to get a tree like (node 3 (empty) (empty)).

Is there a way I could do this without making the auxiliary call?

Thanks!